# PKCS7 encrypt/decrypt image file with OpenSSL

Tags: encryption, openssl, pkcs#7

I'm trying to PKCS7 encrypt and decrypt an image file using OpenSSL.
I've prepared a key-pair and self-signed certificate for doing so.

When doing the encrypt/decrypt roundtrip with a small text file it works.

**Encrypt text file (using the certificate)**

```
openssl smime -encrypt -in data.txt -outform der -out data-encrypted.p7 self-signed-cert-cert.pem
```

**Decrypt (using the private key)**

```
openssl smime -decrypt -inform der -in data-encrypted.p7 -out data-decrypted.txt -inkey self-signed-cert-key.pem
```

After doing so the `data-decrypted.txt` looks exactly the same as the `data.txt` that I gave into encryption.

But when trying the same with a jpg image it doesn't work

**Encrypt jpg (using the certificate)**

```
openssl smime -encrypt -in image.jpg -outform der -out image-encrypted.p7 self-signed-cert-cert.pem
```

**Decrypt (using the private key)**

```
openssl smime -decrypt -inform der -in image-encrypted.p7 -out image-decrypted.jpg -inkey self-signed-cert-key.pem
```

The file `image-decrypted.jpg` is very small although the initial image file `image.jpg` has  82 KB.
When inspecting the `image-encrypted.p7` using OpenSSL it seems to have some data in but possibly not really the image data.

```
$ openssl pkcs7 -in image-encrypted.p7 -inform der -print
PKCS7:
  type: pkcs7-envelopedData (1.2.840.113549.1.7.3)
  d.enveloped:
    version: 0
    recipientinfo:
        version: 0
        issuer_and_serial:
          issuer: C=AU, ST=Some-State, O=mbc-mls-for-xlp-1
          serial: 0x012FFE04FE2573870D8B737E0D09C8B05233DB30
        key_enc_algor:
          algorithm: rsaEncryption (1.2.840.113549.1.1.1)
          parameter: NULL
        enc_key:
          0000 - 0d 3f 5f 0f 24 bd cf b3-27 d2 58 79 6c 52 36   .?_.$...'.XylR6
          000f - c3 64 da c3 c0 23 65 df-d8 a5 e7 7e 4e ab a6   .d...#e....~N..
          001e - ea 3e cf ef 36 7f c8 30-d9 71 5f b7 e9 fb 7b   .>..6..0.q_...{
          002d - d6 a4 c5 2d fb b1 c5 f3-09 a3 a4 97 5c fe f7   ...-........\..
          003c - b7 ab 20 84 1f 86 8a 24-63 7c 20 a7 83 62 43   .. ....$c| ..bC
          004b - fb 5d 6b 85 d0 90 a0 a3-31 95 e3 91 89 0f 60   .]k.....1.....`
          005a - b5 98 78 41 f0 f5 75 ce-fe d1 4b af 33 74 9e   ..xA..u...K.3t.
          0069 - 53 2a ba 60 85 cf 36 22-53 8f 4b 0d 72 27 38   S*.`..6"S.K.r'8
          0078 - 0f 78 43 38 91 67 4c 44-63 28 05 f5 fc f9 8a   .xC8.gLDc(.....
          0087 - 76 db 1e f6 98 2a 4f c6-0b 86 30 66 1c 80 a2   v....*O...0f...
          0096 - c5 05 30 e9 b4 5d 29 78-22 ca e8 d0 70 8e a1   ..0..])x"...p..
          00a5 - fe e5 6f 28 3e cc 87 b7-f0 ad f2 ef 31 66 b7   ..o(>.......1f.
          00b4 - 18 e4 29 a7 45 94 f9 6d-27 47 e1 e0 b4 fa a9   ..).E..m'G.....
          00c3 - a1 b7 2d 2d 60 00 86 4a-47 ba 36 2d b8 9e cd   ..--`..JG.6-...
          00d2 - c1 ba a7 ce 94 09 9a 9f-42 17 7d c9 07 af 97   ........B.}....
          00e1 - cf 75 07 19 77 01 4c ed-93 7e 81 24 ac f3 3f   .u..w.L..~.$..?
          00f0 - e2 6f fc 3c 21 a9 11 29-87 2b 79 30 c4 ff 59   .o.<!..).+y0..Y
          00ff - 76                                             v
    enc_data:
      content_type: pkcs7-data (1.2.840.113549.1.7.1)
      algorithm:
        algorithm: des-ede3-cbc (1.2.840.113549.3.7)
        parameter: OCTET STRING:
          0000 - 14 39 81 49 13 71 90 cd-                       .9.I.q..
      enc_data:
        0000 - c9 20 96 cf fd c2 0e 51-28 b7 51 4b 75 05 8d   . .....Q(.QKu..
        000f - 19 15 ea f8 4c 01 49 43-ed fb eb 07 3b 75 68   ....L.IC....;uh
        001e - 13 f9 1c 15 a7 45 c5 38-6f 3a                  .....E.8o:
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not programming or development, but: by default `smime` (also `cms`) reads data (i.e. `-encrypt -sign` not `-decrypt -verify` which read encoded structure) in text mode; on Windows this terminates if it hits a 'control-Z' (0x1A) and may screw up other bytes (I'm getting data missing for bare LF 0x0A). JPEG is binary data and typically contains all bytes including that/those. **Add `-binary` when encrypting.**

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @dave_thompson_085 the `-binary` flag solves the issue.

Remark: When adding `-binary` to the encryption step I'm getting a proper encrypted file. When decrypting then without the `-binary` the resulting image can be opened but is slightly corrupted. But when adding `-binary` to the decryption step as well the decrypted image is perfectly fine.

So it is:

**Encrypt**

```
openssl smime -encrypt -binary -in image.jpg -outform der -out image-encrypted.p7 self-signed-cert-cert.pem
```

**Decrypt**

```
openssl smime -decrypt -binary -inform der -in image-encrypted.p7 -out image-decrypted.jpg -inkey self-signed-cert-key.pem
```

(I tested this on a Windows machine using OpenSSL 3.1.2 1 Aug 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.1.2 1 Aug 2023))